# How do I pass a Constructor as a Function to a generic method and then use that Constructor in a stream().map() operation?

Tags: java, generics, collections, java-stream

I have a concrete class MyObjectWrapper and an Interface MyObject.

```
MyObjectWrapper implements MyObject
```

MyObjectWrapper.jsonObject holds an instance of MyObjectJson.

The constructor signature for MyObjectWrapper is:

```
MyObjectWrapper(MyObjectJson myObjectJson, ServiceManager serviceManager)
```

I want to provide an instance of PaginatedList to a method and include a reference to the above MyObjectWrapper constructor so it can be referenced for each item in PaginatedList such that the result of my stream() is a new instance of PaginatedList where MyObjectWrapper is the concrete MyObject.

I will have reference to this.getServiceManager() from wherever mapList is called. I am assuming I will have to pass the Constructor for MyObjectWrapper as a Function but am unsure how to write the method signature nor how to properly reference the Constructor as a map function within the method itself.

My code works as written below but I want to make the method generic so I do not have to duplicate it for every type.

```
PaginatedList<T> extends ArrayList<T>
```

```
    private PaginatedList<MyObject> mapList(PaginatedList<MyObjectJson> paginatedList) {
        return paginatedList.stream()
                .map(jsonObject -> new MyObjectWrapper(jsonObject, this.getServiceManager()))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(PaginatedList::new));
    }
```

Comment: You already have an example in your code: `MyObjectWrapper::new`. If you are needing to pre-configure only certain parameters, you can say `moj -> new MyObjectWrapper(moj, serviceManagerVariable)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the constructor takes both a `MyObjectJson` and a `ServiceManager` as input, you don't need a `Function` as input but a `BiFunction<? super MyObjectJson, ? super ServiceManager, ? extends MyObject>`<sup>1</sup>:

```
private PaginatedList<MyObject> mapList(PaginatedList<MyObjectJson> paginatedList,
      BiFunction<? super MyObjectJson, ? super ServiceManager, ? extends MyObject> myObjectProducer) {
    return paginatedList.stream()
            .map(jsonObject -> myObjectProducer.apply(jsonObject, this.getServiceManager()))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(PaginatedList::new));
}
```

and just call it with `mapList(someList, MyObjectWrapper::new)`.

<sup>1</sup> for why the `super`/`extends`, read [What is PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/525036)

Comment: This is great and worked as expected - appreciate the quick and thorough response.